# How to disallow a windows service stop

Tags: security, windows-services

I have some security related service running on my machine (start type = automatic)
In the service control manager, the stop/restart commands are grayed out.

I was wondering how can I develop such service for which the stop operation is disallowed.

Note that I am logged in as an administrator

Comment: Are you writing some kind of malware:-)?

Comment: It does sound like a malware but actually it is not. I just saw another service that does that and figure out I didn't know how to do that. Just curiosity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is to disallow your service to recieve stop requests.

- If you are writing service in C/C++ you should not specify `SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP` flag when calling [SetServiceStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686241%28VS.85%29.aspx) (see [SERVICE_STATUS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685996%28VS.85%29.aspx) for details).
- If your are using .NET, set [ServiceBase.CanStop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.canstop.aspx) to `false`.

Comment: Still, given enough privileges an admin user could kill the process anyway.

Comment: So the CanStop is not related to privileges at all. 
Is it possible to do that privilege based?